# Extended version of the boundedness theorem: $f$ attains its bounds $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $\{f(x) | x \in [a,b]\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been reading an extended version of the boundedness theorem, that also states that if $f$ is bounded, then it attains it bounds, and I've marked the step in the proof that I seem to not understand:

http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L21.html

The proof as linked to:

Let $f$ be defined and continuous at every point in $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is bounded, and to show $f$ attains it bounds, we must show there exists points $\alpha, \beta \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha) = \inf f$ and $f(\beta) = \sup f$. Let $M = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [a,b]\}$. Construct a sequence $\{x_n\}$ like this: for each $n \in \mathbb N$ let $x_n$ be a point such that $f(x_n) =M -\frac 1 n$. Such a point must exists, otherwise $M -\frac 1 n$ is an upper bound smaller than $M$. By Bolzman-Weierstrass some subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, say $(x_{n_k})$ converge to say $\beta$ and $(f(x_{n_1}), f(x_{n_2}), ...) \rightarrow M$ by construction. **By continuity of $f$ we have $f(\beta) = M$ as required**.

**Question:**

Why can we conclude that $f(\delta) = \beta$ ? The only thing we know is that some subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converge, and that $f(x_1), f(x_2), ..$ converge. Does this allow us to write $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{f(x_n)\} = f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n) = f(\delta) = \beta$? If yes, why ?

In general if we know $\{f_n\}$ converge, we cannot be sure $\{x_n\}$ converge. What if $x_n = -1^n$ and $f(x) = k$ a constant function ?

Comment: $x_n \to x \implies f(x_n) \to f(x)$ is often taken as a definition of continuity.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$ instead of $\lim_{n\to \infty}{f_n}$?

Comment: Yes you are right, I've edited. Thanks.

Comment: And $(f(x_1), f(x_2), ...) \rightarrow \beta$, this is extremely misleading. It leads you to think that the function values of the main sequence converge, which in general is not true.

Comment: I didn't edit your thoughts in your Question so maybe you might want to think about it again

Comment: Ohh, I see it now. Since $f(x_n) \rightarrow M = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [a,b]\}$ we have that the convergent subsequence ${x_n}_k$ satisfies $f({x_n}_k) \rightarrow M$ which implies $f(\delta) = M$  for some $\delta \in [a,b]$ since a sequence in a interval must converge to a point in that interval. This is true even thus $x_n$ might not converge at all. So we have found some point $\delta \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\delta) = M$ and we are done.

Comment: Yes, that's right! However in the question it uses $\beta$ but somehow it got changed to $\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the Sequential Criterion for the continuity of real-valued functions.

It's one of the equivalent definitions of continuity on the real line.

$\mathbf{Theorem}$
(Sequential Criterion for Continuity) Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Given a function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$
and a limit point $c\in A$ of $A$, the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is continuous at $c$.
2. $$ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$$
3. For all sequences $(x_n) \subseteq A$ with $lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=c$,
   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) =f(c)$$

Focus on the third definition - you can try to prove this!

Comment: But in the proof above, we just know some subsequence of $x_n$ converges - we cannot say if $x_n$ itself converges to $\delta$. Why does $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(\delta)$ ? Suppose we have some divergent sequence, then indeed $f$ converges for the subsequence, but $f(x_n)$ will not converge !

Comment: A subsequence of $(x_n)$ is a sequence itself, isn't it? So it satisfies the 3rd condition.

Comment: The main sequence here is irrelevant to the proof. I think there's a part in the proof in your question that leads to your confusion.

Comment: But how do I know if $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(\delta) = \beta$ ?  Indeed if we consider the subsequence $x_n^{'}$ that converges in $[a,b]$ to $\delta$ then $f(x_n^{'}) \rightarrow f(\delta)$ (I think the proof linked to should be more explicit here in regards to which sequence is considered). However how can we say $f(\delta) = \beta$, where $\beta$ denote the $\sup \{f(x) | x \in [a,b]\}$ ?? We know $f(x_n)$ converges to $\sup$ by construction, but not that $f(x_n^{'})$  converges to $\sup$ ?? - This is what I have trouble understanding.

Comment: Apparently the proof in your question is filled with symbols that appear out of nowhere. I will edit the proof in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the equivalent definitions of continuity for real functions. You might be used to thinking that a function $f: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $f(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ for all $x_0 \in [a,b]$ (where the limit is one-sided if $x_0 = a$ or $b$) or an equivalent "$\epsilon$, $\delta$-formulation" of this statement. It turns out that $f$ as above is continuous if and only if $x_n \to x \implies f(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $x,x_1,x_2,\ldots \in [a,b]$. In fact, many people take this to be the definition of continuity. (Try to prove this!)

Comment: Should I try to prove this using the formal definition of convergence of sequences and functions ? - I mean using $\lambda $- $\epsilon$ notation ?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ there exists a $\lambda > 0$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)|$ for $|x-c| < \lambda$. Now $x_n \rightarrow c$ so for any $\epsilon$ and corresponding $\lambda$ we can find some $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n - c| < \lambda$ for $n \ge N$. This in turn implies that the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(c)$ by definition and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(c) = f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n)$ ??